# Loop over multiple columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe

I have a dataframe from a CSV file that has 61 columns and 1mil rows. 25 of those columns `(Flag_1, Flag_2, ..., Flag_25)` have `True/False` as values for each row of the dataframe.

What I'm trying to do is loop through each column to determine if there is a True for that entire row within those columns, I just need a minimum of one true. If there is a True then a new column, `Flag_All` will have a True value for that row, if not, then False.

I can use the for loop for a single column like so,

```
for index, x in data2['FLAG_1'].iteritems() :
    data2['FLAG_ALL'] =  data2['FLAG_1'] == True
```

but can't figure out for multiple columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
data2['FLAG_ALL'] = data2.any(axis=1,bool_only=True).values
```

More info on **any()** http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html

Comment: this worked great, but I wonder, if I have other "flags" would this not pick the 'True' in those columns as well? How would I limit this to only the columns FLAG_1 through FLAG_25?

Comment: figured out the column element of it. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 4):

Given an example dataframe of:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'flag_1': [False, False, True],
    'flag_2': [False, False, False],
    'flag_3': [True, False, False]})
```

You can use `df.filter` to get the appropriate columns (those starting with flag, an underscore and then digits...), then apply `any()` across the row axis to get your overall boolean column:

```
df['flag_all'] = df.filter(regex='^flag_\d+$').any(axis=1)
```

Which gives you:

```
  flag_1 flag_2 flag_3 flag_all
0  False  False   True     True
1  False  False  False    False
2   True  False  False     True
```